# asp.net: How to pass input from multiline TextBox to TableAdapter query

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox, dataset, tableadapter

On an asp.net web form, I have: 
multiline TextBox
button
GridView

The TextBox is the entry for `PRODUCT_ID`. When `PRODUCT_ID` is entered in TextBox and button clicked, it will return rows from the Product table and display in GridView.

I created DataSet with TableAdapter. Here's the query for the Get method:

```
SELECT        PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME
FROM            TEST.PRODUCT
WHERE        (PRODUCT_ID = ?)
```

Here's the code:

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        short id = short.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

```
    MyDataSetTableAdapters.PRODUCTTableAdapter idDS = new PRODUCTTableAdapter();

    MyDataSet.PRODUCTDataTable idDT = idDS.GetID(id);

    GridView2.DataSource = idDT;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

It works when I only enter one `PRODUCT_ID` in the TextBox. For example,

**if I enter "8", it will display row from PRODUCT table where PRODUCT_ID = 8;

if I enter "9", it will display row from PRODUCT table where PRODUCT_ID = 9.**

The idea is to enter `PRODUCT_ID` in the TextBox (one or multiple) and display matching rows in GridView.

However, when I tried to enter more than ID in TextBox, for example:
8
9
(then click the button)

It did not work.

> Error message says - {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

How do I pass input from multiline TextBox to TableAdapter query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code design a bit.

First, change your method GetID to accept a string.

```
 public void GetID(string ids)
 {
   //your code
 }
```

Second, change your multiLine Textbox input to comma separated string.

```
  string ids= string.Join(",", TextBox1.Text.Split(' '));
```

Third, change your SQL query where clause.

```
SELECT        PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME
FROM            TEST.PRODUCT
WHERE        (PRODUCT_ID in (ids))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! The solution makes sense. However I am having trouble with the SQL query.  in TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard -> Query Builder, I typed in "SELECT        PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME
FROM            TEST.PRODUCT
WHERE        (PRODUCT_ID in (?))"

Comment: Then click "Execute Query". In the "Query Parameter" popup window, when I entered "8" (no double quotes in entry), it worked; when I entered  "8,9",  I got an error - "Invalid value for cell (row 1, column 2). The changed value in this cell was not reconized as valid. .Net Framework Data Type: Int32".   PRODUCT_ID is smallint. I'm trying different parameter properties (Parameter Collection Editor)...

Comment: Next, I will try adding the code directly in the code behind for Button1_Click().

Comment: I tried the similar query. Yes, Query Parameter popup seems not be accepting multiple values. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873462/not-in-statement-for-visual-studios-query-builder-for-tableadapter. Better if you use ADO.NET function for sql operations.